# Reassign task to multiple users

Tags: tasks, approval-process, task-assignment

How can I reassign task to multiple users at a time. 
The issue is that, it sends the approval to the first name only.

**Note**: The task already configured as parallel

I tried to change the setting of Assigned To column in Task list to allow multiple values. It gives me the following error :

> "cannot change this column to allow multiple values because it is currently being indexed".

What can I do?